# How can I “unlike” a page on a website that’s external to Facebook?

Tags: facebook

I’m helping to develop a website that implements the Facebook “like” button. During testing, I’ve liked a couple of pages on the website with my Facebook account using the like button. I want to “unlike” these pages, so that I can see the like button in its regular state again.

However, I can’t see any record of these likes in my Facebook account. The like button itself doesn’t provide any “unlike” option either, even though it shows the “like” count of the page as 1.

How can I remove my like of these pages?

Comment: Does the like button your using link you to a page on facebook?

Comment: @Matt: it doesn’t. However, I have just spotted it *does* let me reverse my like. Oh dear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah — now it looks like it *does* let me reverse my like of the page.

When I hover over the button, a little cross appears. Clicking on the cross reverses my like of the page.

This cross may have been present before, but I didn’t notice it. Or it may be that when a URL is liked for the first time via the like button, it takes a while for the un-liking functionality to become available.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you are logged in to Facebook.

1. Go to your likes in Facebook and find the external page it links to and copy it (right click and copy url works well); example: https://www.groupon.com/clicky
2. Go to the [Facebook developers page](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) for creating a like button.
3. In the box for "URL to Like" paste in the URL that you copied at step 1.
4. A preview of the like button will appear; it will be greyed out, since you have already liked that page. You can use this preview to unlike that page.

Answer (score 2):

Since Facebook doesn't always show all likes even in your own timeline, you might not be able to see the post showing the unwanted like. Because of that, you might have to go to your activity log:

- Go to your profile
- In the upper-right corner, there is a button to the activity log
- Alternatively, the link is `https://www.facebook.com/[your_user_name]/allactivity`
- The link will be there, can be removed or even marked as spam if necessary

Answer (score 1):

*To give an updated answer for 2021:*

**Step 0 (optional):**

For me, I viewed my profile as "public" and the <Username> likes <external post link> posts appeared. There was no obvious way to delete them besides the below method.

**Step 1:**

Click on the link of the date of the post (ex: July 4th, 2020) and it takes you to the post itself. From there you can click the icon in the top right of the post and delete it.

Comment: Legend. I hunted forever for this and it worked perfectly after trying everything else.